# CSS3 using overlap or side by side positioning in responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm still learning my way around in CSS3 and responsive design.

Stack has been great and has helped in many cases but I am stuck on this one.

I want a responsive site with angled images, so I was trying to use side by side divs that were responsive or divs that overlap. [I found this bit of code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_layers.htm) below but it still not working as expected/desired.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h0dL9jc/) that was a good start, but ultimately I could not get it to adjust smoothly

```
<body>

<div style="background-color:red;
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            position:relative;
            top:10px;
            left:80px;
            z-index:2">
</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow;
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            position:relative;
            top:-60px;
            left:35px;
            z-index:1;">
</div> 
<div style="background-color:green;
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            position:relative;
            top:-220px;
            left:120px;
            z-index:3;">
</div>

</body>
```

So is it best have side by side divs or overlapping divs, for fluid responsive adjustments?

Since I may not be explaining what I'm looking for, this is a sketch of the desired result I'm trying to explain

[image]

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: @SHAYAN I don't think it matters, since hopefully a website should look the same at least in all modern browsers

Comment: Chrome...i didn't consider browser compatibility...bummer if thats an issue too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/7h0dL9jc/9/

html:

```
<body>
    <div style="margin-left: 15%;">
        <div class="box" style="background-color:red;"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.box {
    background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any');
    width:33%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    -ms-transform: skewX(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-5deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skewX(-5deg);
}
```

Comment: That work well and the code is short, thanks.  I'll have to look up all of the styles that you used, the last three are not familiar to me.  Good clean example and you addressed the browser issue.  Great answer.